# How can I download a list of urls but filter by pdf content?

Tags: pdf, url, links, download-manager

I have a large list of links to PDFs. I'd like to download all the PDFs that contain a certain keyword. Is there software that will allow me to input a large list of urls for download but then only download the pdf if its content contains a particular word?

Comment: How will such a software examine the pdf without downloading it?

Comment: I don't know. If that is required, then I'd like software that downloads the pdf, checks it for content, and then deletes it if it doesn't have the specified content. I could just download all the pdfs and then search them, but I don't want to if I don't have to.

Comment: In all cases, you will need to download the entire list, then select the ones that you want to keep.

Comment: You can download em all and then use PowerGrep. But not all PDFs have searchable text (some are just a collection of images)